# (12.04 vm/server) Dist-upgrade to 3.2.0-63 wants to remove git (1.9.2) and git-core - is that the correct behavior?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, git

was wondering if anyone knows dist-upgrade wants to remove git. FWIW, this is a pretty simple box, mainly used for web dev.

```
$ uname -a
Linux precise64 3.2.0-61-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:31:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ git --version
git version 1.9.2

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  git git-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-63 linux-headers-3.2.0-63-generic linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git-man linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server phpmyadmin
5 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 58.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 199 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Edit: including more information:

```
$ apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: 2:1.9.2-0avh1~precise
  Candidate: 2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise
  Version table:
     2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pdoes/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:1.9.2-0avh1~precise 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.7.9.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

$ apt-cache policy git-core
git-core:
  Installed: 2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise
  Candidate: 2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pdoes/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.7.9.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

$ apt-cache policy git-man
git-man:
  Installed: 2:1.9.2-0avh3~precise
  Candidate: 2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise
  Version table:
     2:2.0.0-0avh2~precise 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pdoes/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:1.9.2-0avh3~precise 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.7.9.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit: purged `git`, `git-core`, and `git-man`, and attempted to re-install `git` (note, this caused a bad situation for me, as I rely on both `git` and `virtualenvwrapper`; so I've reverted this machine back to previous/working state):

```
$ sudo apt-get purge git git-core git-man
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  git* git-core* git-man*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 20.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-underscore python-virtualenv wwwconfig-common libjs-jquery javascript-common libjs-sphinxdoc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs
  git-mediawiki git-svn
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bash-completion virtualenvwrapper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 19.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

=====
**Final edit, regarding the [solution from Saiarcot895](https://askubuntu.com/a/476033/155341):** this VM came from a [PuPHPet Vagrant config](http://puphpet.com), which indeed uses that [PPA by pdoes for Git](https://launchpad.net/~pdoes/+archive/ppa) (That wasn't something I had paid attention to up until now). To get things sorted out, I just removed that PPA from my system, and installed the version of Git from the main repository:

```
# apt-add-repository --remove ppa:pdoes/ppa
# apt-get update && apt-get install git -y
# apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: 1:1.7.9.5-1
  Candidate: 1:1.7.9.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.7.9.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Obviously that's an older version of Git, but it's still perfectly acceptable for my needs. And then after that, I was able to run `apt-get dist-upgrade` with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git`, `git-core`, and `git-man` are the relevant packages here.

In the packaging, `git-man` and `git-core` are declared as architecture-independent packages, meaning that these packages can be built once and used on any architecture. `git`, on the other hand, has to be built for each architecture (there are executable files in the package, after all).

What happened most likely here is that when you/the computer ran `sudo apt-get update`, the architecture-independent packages were built (they are built with the i386 binaries), while the architecture-dependent packages weren't built yet. Assuming you are on amd64, this would mean that there is a newer version of `git-core` and `git-man`, but not `git`. Because of the nature of the dependencies specified, you can't have mismatching versions of the three packages. Therefore, `apt` decides to upgrade `git-man` and remove `git` and `git-core`.

The solution is just to wait an hour or two and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again, or (if you really want to/need top upgrade right now) run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which will upgrade as many packages as possible without removing packages.

Edit: The PPA being used here (https://launchpad.net/~pdoes/+archive/ppa) has a `Breaks` condition (at least in the Precise version) for `bash-completion (<< 1:1.90-1)`. The problem: `bash-completion` in Precise is `1:1.3-1ubuntu8.1`. Therefore, `git` from this PPA cannot be installed in Ubuntu Precise without using another PPA for a newer version of `bash-completion`. Some PPAs that have the newer version of `bash-completion` are [this](https://launchpad.net/~voronov84/+archive/andreyv), [this](https://launchpad.net/~zkrynicki/+archive/devtools), and [this](https://launchpad.net/~danmbox/+archive/ppa).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem here, I'm still getting the same output, this is the next day now.

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/476028/edit) your question and add in the outputs of `apt-cache policy git`, `apt-cache policy git-core`, and `apt-cache policy git-man`?

Comment: Gladly, and just updated it!

Comment: @YellowShark: You failed to mention you were using a PPA. At any rate, the depenencies `git-man (>> 2:2.0.0), git-man (<< 2:2.0.0-.)` (in the `git` package) look suspicious to me. Let me do a bit of checking with dpkg versions.

Comment: @YellowShark: The dependencies seem to check out. Can you try removing `git`, `git-core`, and `git-man` and then installing `git`?

Comment: You bet - I just did that, and now it looks like there's some other issues, it wants to uninstall `bash-completion` and `virtualenvwrapper`. I do indeed use a PPA, it's for [NodeJS](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/), which is way out of date in the main repo for Precise (I believe that's still the case at least...). Fairly certain that's the only one I've got in there though.

Comment: (Just an add'l note: that situation broke my workflow, so I reverted to yesterday's backup, which is the original state w/r/t this thread)

Comment: See my edit regarding the removals.

Comment: Thanks very much! That set me straight, and I think I learned a bit more about how to solve similar problems in the future.